# Running a React Dockerfile gives me an error

Tags: docker

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /frontend/

ENV PATH /frontend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is how I built by Dockerfile for my React frontend.
I used `docker build -t frontend:dev .` to build it and `docker run -p 3001:3000 --rm frontend:dev` to run it.

However, this gives me,

> frontend@0.1.0 start /frontend
>   react-scripts start

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /frontend/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`ts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Although I can find `index.html` in `public`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you you did not copy the code in your Dockerfile, as no copy directive execpt package.json?

Add this in your Dockerfile

```
COPY . /frontend/
```

Comment: Can I just replace `COPY package.json /frontend/package.json` with `COPY . /frontend/` so that it just copies everything that I need?

Comment: yes it will copy both, better to add `COPY . /frontend/` as separate directive to keep the cache of `COPY package.json /frontend/package.json` , so do not replace this add new one